# What is the best way to cast from ArrayList to List in .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have a `ArrayList` of type `BookingData` to `List<BookingData>` ?

I am using .net 2.0 so i cannot use `arrayList.Cast<int>().ToList()` , and I dont want to make here foreach loop , do you have better ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: In C# you really need to cast `ArrayList` to `List`?

Comment: @khachik: `ArrayList` is of type `Object` and `List` is a generic type.

Comment: @khachik, they're both concrete classes in C#.

Comment: What's so bad about a foreach-loop (in a method) ?

Comment: @Henk Holterman , nothing bad just wanted to learn something new.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do note that *something* is going to have to enumerate the array-list to construct the `List<T>`; its only a matter of whether you do it yourself or leave it to some other (framework / utility) method.

1. If this is a one-off, the solution that you wish to avoid  (using an "in-place" `foreach` loop to do the conversion) is a perfectly reasonable option. If you find yourself doing this quite often, you could extract that out into a generic utility method, as in cdhowie's answer.
2. If your restriction is only that you must *target* .NET 2.0 (but can use C# 3), consider [LINQBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/), which is a reimplementation of LINQ to Objects for .NET 2.0. This will let you use the `Cast` sample you've provided without change. It will work on C# 2 too, but you won't get the benefits of the extension-method syntax, better type-inference etc.
3. If you don't care about performance, nor do you want to go to the trouble of writing a utility method, you could use the in-built **[`ArrayList.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcyyh2hb.aspx)** method to help out, by creating an intermediary array that plays well with `List<T>` (this isn't all that shorter than a foreach):

---

```
ArrayList arrayList = ...

// Create intermediary array
BookingData[] array = (BookingData[]) arrayList.ToArray(typeof(BookingData));

// Create the List<T> using the constructor that takes an IEnumerable<T>
List<BookingData> list = new List<BookingData>(array);
```

Finally, I would suggest, if possible to abandon using the obsolete non-generic collection-classes altogether.

Comment: Just FYI, this method will create an unnecessary intermediate array.

Answer (score 2):

Let's keep it simple:

```
// untested
List<T> ConvertArrayList<T>(ArrayList data)
{
    List<T>  result = new List<T> (data.Count);
    foreach (T item in data)
      result.Add(item);
    return result;
}

...

List<BookingData> newList = ConvertArrayList<BookingData>(oldList);
```

Comment: You need to cast `item` to `T`.

Comment: @cdhowie: If memory serves the foreach will do that. Old Fx2 voodoo.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
public static List<T> ConvertToList<T>(ArrayList list)
{
    if (list == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

    List<T> newList = new List<T>(list.Count);

    foreach (object obj in list)
        newList.Add((T)obj);

    // If you really don't want to use foreach:
    // for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    //     newList.Add((T)list[i]);

    return newList;
}
```

Then you can:

```
List<BookingData> someList = ConvertToList<BookingData>(someArrayList);
```

Comment: .NET 2.0 compiler doesn't support extension methods and var.

Comment: @TToni: True enough. That's only a syntactic difference though. I'll fix it.

Comment: @TToni actually it *can* - it is C# 2.0 that can't. But you can use C# 3.0 targeting .NET 2.0 with extension methods.

Comment: @Marc: You can make the same argument for LINQ. Extension methods require the 3.5 libraries to supply the special extension method attribute, just like LINQ requires the 3.5 libraries.

Comment: Needs to be `newList.Add`, btw

Comment: I know it's the compiler, not the clr. Anyway, the OP made it clear he cannot use 3.x features.

Comment: @Marc: D'oh! It's been a long day. Fixed.

Comment: @cdhowie - no, it just needs *an attribute of the right name*; it doesn't strictly need to come from the 3.5 libraries.

Comment: C£ 2.0 does not have var keyword

Comment: @Saurabh: Ah, the things you get used to on 3.5... fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `foreach`:

```
        foreach (Object item in list1)
        {
            list2.Add((BookingData)item);
        }
```

Comment: Any `other loop construct` will... But you have to loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

ToList() method is nothing but the Synthetic sugar for creating a List representation but internally it is also using loop to generate the list item.

so it is much cleaner and simpler to use a foreach iterator block.